# Features of Resettable Fuses

Tags: polyfuse

I want to use a resettable fuse for overcurrent protection. I am a bit confused about their features. The hold current is the maximum current for not tripping and the trip current is the mimimum current for tripping, right? Then, what is the current rating? Also, regarding the ambient temperature, I am going to use the fuse inside an enclosure. Should I consider a higher than ~25 C degrees temperature for selecting the right hold current?

Comment: Be aware that resettable fuses are not precision devices by any means. Also be aware that their current threshold specs will change with temperature and the number of times that the device has tripped.